# Click events getting routed to the wrong view

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview

I have a window with two views in it:

[image: Most of the window is taken up by a PRH Movie View, while the bottom 20 points of the window belong to a PRH Controller View.]

Both the movie view and the controller view override `mouseDown:` and `mouseUp:`, for different purposes (the movie view has a target and action and reacts as a button, whereas the controller seeks and supports dragging).

The twist is, when I click within the movie view—which, as shown in the screenshot, will generally be large enough to make missing it and hitting the controller view instead wildly improbable—the `mouseDown:` and `mouseUp:` messages are sent to the controller view! The movie view never receives either message.

I have not overridden `hitTest:` in the movie view or in its parent view (which is a plain NSView), only in the controller view (for reasons that have to do with a tracking area I have on that view—my implementation simply returns `self`, which is the controller view).

So, what gives?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you probably guessed it: It was my `hitTest:` implementation in the controller view.

It turns out that `hitTest:` is not only sent to the views whose frames the mouse location lies within; it is sent to *every* view in the window, even views that were nowhere near the mouse at either end of the click.

So, when overriding `hitTest:`, make sure that you verify that the point is actually within yourself. The simplest way is to send `[super hitTest:thePoint]` and only do your custom hit-test if the result is not `nil`. (Unless you *want* to steal clicks from other views in the window.)